# When I use an href to return to a previous page, part of the page flashes before the page is painted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

page A transfers to page B via 
     window.location.href = "ww_Cart.html";
When the user needs to return to page A from page B, the screen flashes with part of page A before correctly loading the page.  Does anyone have any idea where I should look?

thanks in advance.
Ann Maybury

Comment: An example URL please.  We can't help you by guessing in the dark.  It shouldn't be happening, and a URL would help us find out why.  Also let us know what browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this was caused by the load time associated with switching back and forth between different html files.    I solved it by putting the different view into one html and them managing the visiblity myself.  Please close.